How to sum the cost of relationships
I want to get the lowes cost form a knot to a knot but I only get a list of relationships
MATCH (g:city {name:"Graz"})-[c:bus*]->(b:city {name:"Bregenz"})
RETURN c.fahrzeit

this statement gives me a :
Type mismatch: expected Map, Node, Relationship, Point, Duration, Date, Time, LocalTime, LocalDateTime or DateTime but was List<Relationship> (line 2, column 8 (offset: 72))
"RETURN c.fahrzeit"

but the statement:
MATCH (g:city {name:"Graz"})-[c:bus*]->(b:city {name:"Bregenz"})
RETURN c

workes and gives me only the list. Ultimately, i would like the shortest journey time (fahrzeit)

You need to sum the values of the fahrzeit property of each of the relationships in the list c. This can be done with the reduce function:
MATCH (g:city { name: "Graz" })-[c:bus*]->(b:city { name: "Bregenz" })
RETURN reduce(acc = 0, rel IN c | acc + rel.fahrzeit) AS gesamt

